# x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Currently I am trying to build an App that I wrote in Python and Kivy via buildozer. Whatever I am doing, I am running into problems with window_x11. Even if I comment all the windows related things out in the code or doing all the things described in this post.

Here is a part of the error generated:

> x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'

Another strange aspect is that I am using Python-3.x, but it keeps on saying about python-2.7.

```
running cython ./kivy/core/window/window_x11.pyx
()                                                                             
           working:Exception in thread background thread for pid 20337:        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2170, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1929, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/local/bin/cython ./kivy/core/window/window_x11.pyx

  STDOUT:

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.base import stopTouchApp, EventLoop, ExceptionManager
from kivy.utils import platform
from os import environ

from window_info cimport WindowInfoX11
^
```

Currently I am lost in what to do and I also don't know where to start to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug introduced in Kivy master, which is fixed in python-for-android's master branch. You can probably work around it by setting `p4a.branch = master` in the buildozer.spec, or using an older version of Kivy than the master branch (ideally Kivy 1.10).

Comment: I have tried your proposal, but it doesnt seem to work. I updated the buildozer.spec file with your proposal. I also checked which Kivy Im using and that seems to be 1.10.1. Still, I get the same error. I also removed python and re-installed as well as buildozer. Will it be something with a version control or so? Like I said, I do get messages that point towards python 2.7 while the program is written in python3.5. Could it be caused by thins? 

I have python-for-android 0.6.0 and I did a re-install with the following command: 
pip install git+https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git

Comment: I would go with the `p4a.branch = master` method as the most reliable. Did you also clean the buildozer build, e.g. by deleting the `.buildozer` file in your app directory (the one containing your buildozer.spec)?

Comment: @inclement hi, I got the same issue. You solution didn't help me. I removed .buildozer folder as well. The same issue

Comment: @inclement could you share commit when p4a version works well?

Comment: Sorry for the what late response (having a kid now really consumes time that I usually spend on programming ...). The p4abranch and remove the .buildozer did not help me as well.

Comment: The issue seems to pop-up more on the internet: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/536