# Buildozer gives error 'WindowInfoX11' is not a type identifier

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am using python 2.7.12, buildozer 0.34, cython 0.25.2 and kivy 1.10.0. I am planning to display ads on my app using KivMob. I already have my test device ID and APP_ID. And I tried this code from [KivMob](https://github.com/MichaelStott/KivMob).

```
from kivmob import KivMob
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class KivMobTest(App):

    def build(self):
        ads = KivMob("ca-app-pub-APP_ID")
        ads.add_test_device("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
        ads.new_interstitial("ca-app-pub-INTERSTITIAL_ID")
        ads.request_interstitial()
        return Button(text='Show Interstitial',
                      on_release= lambda a:ads.show_interstitial())
```

And wrote this in the buildozer.spec:

```
requirements = kivy, hostpython2, android, kivmob
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
p4a.source_dir = /python-for-android-admob/
p4a.bootstrap = sdl2-admob
```

But when I ran the command "buildozer -v android debug", it gives an error:

```
kivy/core/window/window_x11.pyx:221:13: 'WindowInfoX11' is not a type identifier


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2-admob --requirements=kivy,hostpython2,android,kivmob --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/ken/testads/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I tried to build a simple hello world button app which uses same version of python, buildozer, cython and kivy from the above. And used the python-for-android-master.

```
p4a.source_dir = /python-for-android-master/
```

and the simple hello world button app was successfully created.

I really wanted to display ads on my app. I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue and solved by quick setting change.

```
I use Buildozer 0.35dev, Cython 0.21.2, Python 2.7.12 and Kivy 1.9.0
```

This issue is related to Kivy version under python-for-android (not Kivy installed in PC).
[x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477845/x11-importerror-no-module-named-kivy-core-window-window-x11)

Master branch is the default Kivy under KivMob python-for-android, so changing this to another version (version 1.10.0 in my case) solves the issue.

Following the steps below:

- Go to Kivy recipe folder of KivMob `$HOME/python-for-android-admob/pythonforandroid/recipes/kivy`,
- `open __init_.py`
- *edit line 9* (`version = 'master'`) as follows:
  `version ='1.10.0'`